# how to get cell value in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my iphone application I have 4 cell in uiTable, and each cell having Integers values(10, 12, 13, 14).How to retrieve the integer value while I click on each cell?
And how to put if condition to check whether the value of the cell is same or not?
I.e.

```
if(cell value==condition){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method in your `UITableViewController` simply extract the labels text value.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *s = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
    NSLog(@"String is: %@", s);

    int i = [s intValue];
    NSLog(@"This is the int value: %d", i);

    // Compare string or int to other value...
}
```